# How to interpret numpy.gradient?

Tags: numpy

In the first example of the documentation
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16], dtype=np.float)
np.gradient(x)
array([ 1. ,  1.5,  2.5,  3.5,  4.5,  5. ])
```

Isn't the output should be:

```
array([ 1. ,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5. ])
```

???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you expect as output is what you will get when running `np.diff`, but then one element shorter:

```
np.diff(arr)
>>> array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.])
```

`np.gradient` looks takes the i'th element and looks at the average between the differences for the `(i+1)`'th vs. `i`'th element and the `(i-1)`'th vs. `i`'th element. For the edge values it only can use one point. So value number two comes `1.5` comes from averaging `(2-1)` and `(4-2)`.

Answer (score 15):

Numpy-gradient uses `forward`, `backward`, and `central` differences where appropriate.

Input:

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 4, 7, 11, 16], dtype=np.float)
np.gradient(x)      # this uses default distance=1
```

Output:

> array([ 1. ,  1.5,  2.5,  3.5,  4.5,  5. ])

For the first item it uses forward (current -> next) difference:

- previous number: none

- current (first) number: 1

- next number:    2

   (2 - 1) / 1  = 1.

For the last item it uses backward (previous -> current) difference:

- previous number: 11

- current (last) number: 16

- next number:    none

(16 - 11) / 1 = 5.

And, for the items in between, the central difference is applied:

- previous number: 1

- current number: 2

- next number:    4

(4 - 1) / 2 = 1.5


- previous number: 2

- current number: 4

- next number:    7

(7 - 2) / 2 = 2.5

 ...

and so on:-

(11 - 4) / 2 = 3.5

(16 - 7) / 2 = 4.5

The differences are divided by the sample distance (default=1) for forward and backward differences, but twice the distance for the central difference to obtain appropriate gradients.